# How to rebase already merged commits

Tags: git, merge, commit, rebase

I need to retroactively `rebase` `merged commits` from `master` onto a feature branch.

The feature branch was branched off of `master` (feature branch is the the blue line in the picture), then there were multiple commits on the feature branch (blue dots) , then master was merge committed back to the feature branch (instead of rebased - master is the red line in the picture).

So I need to "go back" 2 `merge commits` and rebase them instead while keeping the feature branch intact.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also reset your branch to the commit before you split with the master branch, and then commit all your changes into 1 squashed commit.
After that, simply rebase on master.

so, on your branch:

```
git reset --soft <commit SHA>
git add <All changes>
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git rebase master
```

Comment: Awesome . You are an amazing person and have a place in heaven

Answer (score 0):

You can use git rebase -i  and replace "pick" on the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or "fixup".

Detailed description here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode

After you did that you need to push to the remote repo (I think with a force).